# css border overflows to text

Tags: css, image, grid, border

I am trying to add  tag with a border as a layer in front of a gallery grid I am making.

My code is this:

*HTML*

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="grid-item25"> <a href="#" class="bordered">
            &nbsp;
        </a>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        <a href="#" style="display:block;">test</a>        
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item25"> <a href="#" class="bordered">
            &nbsp;
        </a>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        <a href="#" style="display:block;">test</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* Removes padding behaviour on widths */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.wrap {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.wrap:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.grid-item25 {
    max-width: 25%;
    min-height: 202px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.bordered {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 90000;
    border:1px solid white;
    left: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
    top:1rem;
    bottom:1rem;
}
```

The result is this: http://jsfiddle.net/ditikos/7LGBD/ but the problem is that the border instead of staying at the bottom of the image (at 0.5rem) it overflows to the text as well.

Can someone help me to understand why this happens and it does not stay where it should have been?

Thanks

Comment: Yes but inseted. Without the text it places perfectly, but adding it it makes the absolute positioning to the whole of the grid height (including image).

Comment: Can you try to explain further what you need here? I have a feeling you're barking up the wrong tree but I can't tell what you want from the explanation.

If you need an image to also be a clickable link nest the <img> inside the <a> in the html.

Comment: It's what zeroworks is trying to show. I am trying to make a responsive image with a border that grows/shrinks and is less than the width/height of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace bordered class:

```
.bordered {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 90000;
    border:1px solid white;
    left: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
    top:1rem;
    bottom:1rem;
    margin: 0 0 1.5rem 0;
}
```

And will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Will this work for example if the text is 4-5 lines of code or will it have to be reconfigured? This is part of a responsive grid so I am curious (I haven't used percentage as a height because it always fails to be calculated correctly).

Comment: I've updated... now it grows as you need. Test it replacing `max-width` from `.grid-item25` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide `height` for the `class bordered`, the problem become rectified..

**Eg:**

```
.bordered
 {
   height: 47%;
 }
```

Fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/7LGBD/1/

This is only an example way ...If you not interested in this please ignore..